# How can I wait for AJAX before doing a Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax call I want to run on form submit to populate a value then I want to submit the form. The closest I can find to this is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#dealform').submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

            //Do the AJAX
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Admin/deals/dealload",
                data: //the data
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {

                    res = response;

                    jQuery('#post_data').val(res[0].message); // update the value

                    jQuery(this).unbind('submit').submit(); // this doesn't fire

                }

        });
    });
});
```

How can I get the submit function to fire after preventing the event? or if because I am using .submit( with event prevent default is there another way to trigger the submit on ajax complete ?

Comment: `jQuery(this).unbind('submit').submit();` ... the problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is at this point - `success: (response) =>  {` will fix that
`

Comment: jQuery('#dealform').submit() will submit the form